# Invalid URL error while saving Power BI report to SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Saving reports created in Power BI Desktop Technical Preview to a correctly configured Stand-alone SQL Server Reporting Services returns an 'invalid url' error.
The Stand-alone Reporting Service database are stored in the SQL Server 2012 database engine.[image: Saving to Report server URL(IP address]

[image: Saving to Report Server URL]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove "reportserver" from the New Report Server address. The hodentek8/ReportServer is the service address, and you're after the Report Manager portal address, which would be http://hodentek8/reports

Comment: You are right. The Server selection page in Power BI is misleading. In any case you can only save reports that use data from an Analysis Services server, not any report from Power BI.